# ion-text-center doesn't center the content within div

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I want to center a text inside a `div`

```
<ion-content>
    <form>
        <ion-grid>
            <ion-row class="ion-justify-content-start">
                <ion-col></ion-col>
            </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
        <ion-button>
            login
        </ion-button>
      <div>
         <ion-text class="ion-text-center">forgot password?</ion-text>
       </div>
    </form>
</ion-content>
```

the text inside the `ion-text` tag is not centered even after using `ion-text-center` class.

Comment: Could you please post more of your code?

Comment: yes i added the complete code

Answer (score 0):

solved like this

```
<div class="ion-text-center">
    <ion-text>forgot password?</ion-text>
</div>
```